# C# GhostScript - Not able to successfully convert from PDF to TXT file

Tags: c#, winforms, process, ghostscript

I have been successful with extracting text from a PDF file using GhostScript along with the following command line arguments:

```
gswin32c.exe ^
  -q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND ^
  -dWRITESYSTEMDICT ^
  -dSIMPLE ^
  -c save ^
  -f ps2ascii.ps ^
   "test.pdf" ^
  -c quit ^
  >"test.txt"
```

Points to note: I copied the following three files from the installation directory into my C:\ directory.

```
1)gsdll32.dll
2)gsdll32.lib
3)gswin32
```

When manually running GhostScript through the command line I do the following:
Run > CMD > cd C:\ (then proceed to input the above arguments).

(The above command works and a new file named "test.txt" appears in my C:\ drive with the appropriate pdf data).

**When attempting to execute `GhostScript` through the command line, however, I am not successful.**

In my C# Winform Application, I am using the following code to execute GhostScript:

```
Process p1 = new Process();
p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\test.exe";
                    p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                    p1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\";
                    p1.StartInfo.Arguments = " -q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dSIMPLE -c save -f ps2ascii.ps " + quote + @"C:\h.pdf" + quote + " -c quit >" + quote + @"C:\test.txt" + quote;
                    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\hhh.txt", p1.StartInfo.Arguments);
                    p1.Start();
```

Does anyone see any obvious errors with my code? I would appreciate any help I can get here.

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: One obvious error is that you seem to be running test.exe in your code and not gsWin32c.exe

Comment: First what exactly is quote? Second your starting the wrong application. Third the file you are creating even if you were starting the correct file would not contain the contents of test.txt.  Lets just skip all the questions and just read this: http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/tag/ghostscriptsharp/

Comment: I renamed it to Test.exe - this IS the correct application. Also, quote is a constant for '\u0022' which is a " symbol

Comment: @Evan - Assume this is a constant you defined?

Comment: Yes, and I confirmed the constant worked correctly

Comment: Your part `-f ps2ascii.ps` may not be found by your C# code. Try specifying the complete path to the *ps2ascii.ps* file....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a batch file named `batch.bat` as follows.

   ```
   rem batch.bat
   rem %1 represents input file name without extension.
   echo off
   gswin32c -q -dNODISPLAY -dSAFER -dDELAYBIND -dWRITESYSTEMDICT -dSIMPLE -c save -f ps2ascii.ps %1.pdf -c quit >%1.txt
   ```
2. Compile the following code to get a console application named `myapp.exe`

   ```
   using System.Diagnostics;

   class myapp
   {
       public static void Main()
       {
           Process p1 = new Process();
           p1.StartInfo.FileName = "batch.bat";
           p1.StartInfo.Arguments = "test";
           p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

           p1.Start();
           p1.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
   ```
3. Put all in the same directory as follows and double click the `myapp.exe`. Done!

[image]

Comment: I would love to just show you what is going on once this executes. GhostScript seems to be running but I cannot read the command prompt as GhostScript closes it automatically (so i have no idea what the actual error is). All of my files (ghostscript files along with pdf file) are in the same directory (not in the C drive but on my desktop). there are no errors thrown by Visual Studio. If you have teamviwer or any other remote app i would love to show you  what is going on!

Comment: Talk about a WELL deserved answer! woahh!